# how to group into a single record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

hi i have a problem with oracle

I want to do the following

```
select name, type from table_1 where name = 'carlos' group by type, name;
```

what I returned two records

```
|name |type|
|Carlos| 3 |
|Carlos| 4 |
```

What I want to do is to get a single record out of the following form

```
|name| type|
|Carlos| 3,4 |
```

I tried it with the rtrim but it gets me many times the type I only want it to come out once

```
Select Name, rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,type||’,’) type 
Where name = 'carlos' group by name;
```

what I returned one records

```
|name| type|
|Carlos| 3,4,4,4|
```

could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [`listagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function :

```
select name, listagg(type,',') within group (order by type) 
  from table_1 
 where name = 'carlos' 
 group by name
```

If you have repeating `type` values and want to distinct get in the comma-seperated string result, then use :

```
select name, listagg(type,',') within group (order by type) 
  from
  (
   select distinct name, type 
     from table_1 
    where name = 'carlos' 
  )
  group by name
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8d34865a73493a137b149eb67cbf8dde)</kbd>